# Why is the 'anonymousUser' authenticated in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, authentication, spring-security

This is my main controller:

```
package org.demian.demibox.controllers;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    private String getUsername() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth.isAuthenticated())
            return auth.getName();
        else
            return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome() {
        String username = getUsername();
        System.out.println(username);
        if (username == null || username.length() == 0)
            return "welcome";
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Even though I am not logged in, `auth.isAuthenticated()` always returns `true`. Why is that? And when would `auth.isAuthenticated()` return false? The name of the authenticated user is `anonymousUser` if I'm not logged in and username if I am logged in.

### EDIT

This is my `security-context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="jdbcUserService" />
            <!-- <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" /> -->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/redeem" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/redeem_code" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:remember-me key="offersAppKey" user-service-ref="jdbcUserService" />
    </security:http>
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <!-- <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" /> -->
</beans>
```

And the following lines are in the `web.xml` file:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am using Tomcat 8.0 and all the latest dependencies via Maven.

Comment: Please add the Spring-Security configuration to the question

Comment: Check whether `Authentication` object is `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` or not.

Comment: Yes. It works! You can put that as an answer.

Comment: But I still don't understand why `isAuthenticated()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is how spring-security works by default.

From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/anonymous.html):

> Note that there is no real conceptual difference between a user who is "anonymously authenticated" and an unauthenticated user. Spring Security’s anonymous authentication just gives you a more convenient way to configure your access-control attributes. Calls to servlet API calls such as `getCallerPrincipal`, for example, will still return null even though there is actually an anonymous authentication object in the `SecurityContextHolder`.
>
> There are other situations where anonymous authentication is useful, such as when an auditing interceptor queries the `SecurityContextHolder` to identify which principal was responsible for a given operation. Classes can be authored more robustly if they know the `SecurityContextHolder` always contains an `Authentication` object, and never null.

If you need to check if it is an `anonymousUser` then you can check whether `Authentication` object is `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` instance or not.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this answer in other questions on the net but I was reticent to using it because I think it's best to avoid when possible `instanceof`.

Comment: @Ariel: You can also check `authorities` from `Authentication` object for `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`.

Comment: The token 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS' is hardcoded as a String in several places of Spring Security lib. Is it reliable to use it? I mean, the compiler will not detect the error in case of typo or refactoring.

Comment: @beemaster Spring security is an open source project you can provide patch for that.

Comment: well, I even didn't think about it. I used to think that Spring's team are 'top level' developers and I'll look humble on this background.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: @NicHartley yes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31681783/2342529) answer, but in my opinion is better not to.

Comment: When does spring does this ? In which case the returned Authentication is an anonymousUser ?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Why is it better not to disable this behavior???