# Prevent Spring Boot from registering one of Spring Security filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I would like to disable one of the Spring Security filters in security chain.

I have already saw [Prevent Spring Boot from registering a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421966/prevent-spring-boot-from-registering-a-servlet-filter) question - and accepted should work but, unfortunately is not.

With code:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registration(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }
```

Spring Boot will promptly announce there is no qualifying bean, which is sad:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

After creating another bean:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // Oh, there be dragons
    @Bean
    public AnonymousAuthenticationFilter anonymousAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new AnonymousAuthenticationFilter();
    }
```

I am attacked with

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this String argument must have length; it must not be null or empty

Which is entirely understable; `Assert`s in `afterPropertiesSet()` method https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java are preventing me from using default constructor. Using another approach:

```
    @Bean
    public AnonymousAuthenticationFilter anonymousAuthenticationFilter() {
        // it will be disabled anyway so...
        return new AnonymousAuthenticationFilter("_", new Object(), new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
    }
```

Everything is way nicer:

> INFO  4916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Filter anonymousAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
>
> DEBUG 4916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
>
> DEBUG 4916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured successfully

But after accessing some resource I got:

> DEBUG 4916 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
>
> DEBUG 4916 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90572420: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6B9D974A4634548750FE78C18F62A6B0; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

For some reason AnonymousAuthenticationFilter is still working.
The question: Is there a way to disable such filters in Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Spring Security bundles all of the Filters within the `HttpSecurity` configuration. To disable anonymous authentication use the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .anonymous().disable()
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to disable all of the defaults within Spring Security you can pass true into the parent class constructor to disable defaults. For example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I spent so many hours searching through internet, documentations and source code when solution was always so close. You are my hero.

Comment: I have to say when it comes to spring, it's always like that. So many way to do the same thing that you get conused.

Comment: totally agree with above comment, I had keycloak as well and searching around to see from where this "anonymousUser" coming in...

Comment: Thank you, but I got "AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
When added: 
  http.anonymous().disable();
Before configure swagger access:
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/",
    "/v2/api-docs",
    "/swagger-resources",
    "/swagger-resources/**",
    "/configuration/ui",
    "/configuration/security",
    "/swagger-ui.html",
    "/webjars/**",
    "/v3/api-docs/**",
    "/swagger-ui",
    "/swagger-ui/**",
    "/favicon.ico",
    "/csrf"
  ).permitAll();
What do I wrong?

Comment: If you have requirement to have Spring Actuators public, like for example a public /health actuator, setting anonymous().disable() will force it to require authentication.  If that is not the requirement, then it is a problem