# Spring Security - Difference between a user with a ROLE_ANONYMOUS and an unauthenticated user

Tags: java, spring-security

In Spring Security, we have a  “anonymously authenticated user ” = `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` role. What is the benefit and use case of this role? More specifically how is it different from an unauthenticated user?

This [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html) goes into some detail, but I really am not able to understand in what situations a `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` would be useful.

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101738/why-is-the-anonymoususer-authenticated-in-spring-security/26117007#26117007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the 'anonymousUser' authenticated in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101738/why-is-the-anonymoususer-authenticated-in-spring-security)